# Optimising Images for Web Application

Tags: image, optimization

Sites such as http://themeforest.net , http://photodune.net/ , https://www.flickr.com and other imaging sites *appear* to optimise their images. For example, Photodune shows the images for sell as a thumbnail before the user clicks on the product taking you to the main sale page. You can then choose to buy Extra Small, Small, Medium.. etc. This goes for Flickr too, you can choose to view different resolutions of the same photo. So, my question is this:

When a web application user uploads an image, does the web application automatically optimise multiple resolutions of the same image (say a thumbnail for displaying in a feed and a large version for its own blog post for example). And if it does how would you do this? (code example would be great) and is it a popular method of displaying images for different sizes?

Comment: There will be other tools too but maybe have a look at http://www.imagemagick.org/

Comment: I think you need to think about what you are optimising FOR? Responsiveness to the user? Volume of data on the server? Number of files on the server - some hosting packages only allow 200,000 files for example.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thats what I am asking, whats best? And how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an ASPX script in VB years ago to re-size images. The original image file is stored on the server. When you request the image, you specify the size you want and the image is re-sized on the server, then sent to the client.

So with one image, I can request any size I want. I'm not sure if that's how Flickr and others do it, but it worked for a low traffic site on a host that allocated a very small amount of space.

This code is very old, and might not be the best way to do it, but it works.

```
' Open the file specified in the request.
Dim sSrc As String = Request.QueryString("SRC")
Dim oImg As System.Drawing.Image
oImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(sSrc))

' Get the requested width.
Dim iWidth As Integer
iWidth = Request.QueryString("W")

' Get the requested height.
Dim iHeight As Integer
iHeight = Request.QueryString("H")

' Calculate the aspect ratio if either H or W are zero.
If iWidth > 0 And iHeight = 0 Then
    iHeight = oImg.Height / (oImg.Width / iWidth)
End If
If iWidth = 0 And iHeight > 0 Then
    iWidth = oImg.Width / (oImg.Height / iHeight)
End If

' Resize the image.
Dim iQuality As Integer = 100
Dim oThumb As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(iWidth, iHeight)
Dim oGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(oThumb)
oGraphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
oGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
oGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
oGraphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
oGraphics.DrawImage(oImg, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight)

' Load the JPEG encoder and set the quality parameter.
Dim oEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
oEncoder = GetImageEncoder("JPEG")
Dim oParameters As New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
Dim oParameter As New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, iQuality)
oParameters.Param(0) = oParameter

' Save the new image to the response stream.
Response.Clear
Response.ContentType = oEncoder.MimeType
oThumb.Save(Response.OutputStream, oEncoder, oParameters)

' Release the resources used by the image objects.
oParameter.Dispose()
oParameters.Dispose()
oGraphics.Dispose()
oThumb.Dispose()
oImg.Dispose()

Private Shared Function GetImageEncoder(ByVal FormatDescription As String) As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
    Dim oEncoders() As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
    Dim oEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo
    oEncoders = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
    For Each oEncoder in oEncoders
        If oEncoder.FormatDescription = FormatDescription Then
            Return oEncoder
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

This doesn't have any error handling, I only copied the useful bits into this. Also, this is just for requesting the image from the server, it doesn't put the image on the server.

Comment: This gives me a great insight :) Thank you!